# Matplotlib changing axis ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have a few lines of making a scatter plot out of a collection of points (x<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>0</sub>), ... (x<sub>n</sub>,y<sub>n</sub>).

The truth is that I am only interested in the x scale as it is the scale on which the graph is power law behaved but after plotting I would like to replace the ticks on the x-axis by some other function of `$x_i$`.

How could I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell matplotlib where to put the x-axis labels by

```
ax.set_xticks(positions)
```

where `positions` is a list of tick positions in the scale which your data is using for x-positioning and `ax` is the axis to plot on (`ax=plt.gca()` or `ax=fig.gca()`). You can then set the tick labels:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Example: you want to display x-ticks in log scale but still use a linear scale for the x-axis (not very useful, I know):

```
positions = np.array([1, 10, 100, 1000])
ax.set_xticks(positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(np.log10(positions))
```

Note however, that this won't change the x-scale of your data!